# using read_excel to get multiple sheets with different col_types set

Tags: r, purrr, readxl

I want to read a excel file with multiple sheets and specify col_types to each sheet, the following is my code:

```
data_file <- "./input/data.xlsx"

sheet_names <- c("Sales", "Customs", "Departments")

col_type_list <- list(
  Sales = c(rep("text", 3), rep("numeric", 2)),
  Customs = rep("text", 5),
  Departments = rep("text", 4)
)

DList <- purrr::map2(.x = sheet_names, .y = col_type_list,
  .f = read_xlsx(
    path = data_file,
    sheet = .x,
    col_types = .y
  )
)
```

execute above code and get the following error message:

```
Error in standardise_sheet(sheet, range, sheets_fun(path)) : 
  object '.x' not found
```

how can i put correct .x and .y into the code?

Comment: I think it would be `map2(.x=sheet_names, .y=col_type_list, .f = ~ read_xlsx(`. Everything after that can stay the same. The key is to use `~` to tell `map2` that what's coming is not just a function name (like `read_xlsx` by itself), but a formula that should be turned into a function call. See the `.f` section of the help for `map2`. (Also, the `.x=`, `.y=`, and `.f=` are not necessary, but it does no harm to include them.)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, but you're missing the tilde before invoking read_xlsx.

Here it is with the tilde (~) added and it runs smoothly :)

```
data_file <- "./input/data.xlsx"

sheet_names <- c("Sales", "Customs", "Departments")

col_type_list <- list(
  Sales = c(rep("text", 3), rep("numeric", 2)),
  Customs = rep("text", 5),
  Departments = rep("text", 4)
)

DList <- purrr::map2(.x = sheet_names, .y = col_type_list,
                     .f = ~read_xlsx(
                       path = data_file,
                       sheet = .x,
                       col_types = .y
                      )
)
```